# override an activity on another

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-tabhost

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjSL7.jpg)This is my code snippet

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();    
TabSpec aboutus = tabHost.newTabSpec("About us");
aboutus.setIndicator("___", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_aboutus_tab));
Intent photosIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), readmore.class);

aboutus.setContent(photosIntent);
TabSpec contactus = tabHost.newTabSpec("Contact us");
// setting Title and Icon for the Tab
contactus.setIndicator("___", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_contactus_tab));
Intent songsIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), contactus.class);
contactus.setContent(songsIntent);
TabSpec orderhistory = tabHost.newTabSpec("Order history");
orderhistory.setIndicator("___", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_orderhistory_tab));
Intent videosIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), readmore.class);
orderhistory.setContent(videosIntent);
TabSpec home = tabHost.newTabSpec("Home");
home.setIndicator("___", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_home_tab));
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Mainpage.class);
homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
home.setContent(homeIntent);
// Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
tabHost.addTab(aboutus); // Adding about us tab
tabHost.addTab(contactus); // Adding contact us tab
tabHost.addTab(orderhistory); // Adding order history tab
tabHost.addTab(home);
```

[image: This is my screen shot on emulato]

The Intent is not overriding the main activity.
how am i supposed to override it.

This is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidhive.xmlparsing"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/zaggleicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" 

    >`<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AndroidTabLayoutActivity" >
        <intent-filter >

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".readmore" >
        <intent-filter >

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>` <activity android:name=".Mainpage">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".contactus" >
        <intent-filter >

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`
```

From my image it is showing that when i press the button the activit is showing in particular portion and the last activity remains same in the activity.So how to override that activty when i press the tab button.

Comment: What do you mean by 'The Intent is not overriding the main activity'?

Comment: if u see the image when i press the tab button the activity is loading in the bottom but not full screen. The prevoius activity still lies in the screen.

Comment: Is this happening for every activity?

Comment: yes this is happening in every tab button i press

Comment: Show us your manifest file. And, have a look at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/) tutorial

Comment: @SpK I have shown my manifest file in question now.

Comment: Where'd you declare the other activities `(readmore, contactus, Mainpage)`?

Comment: Let us continue this discussion [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people) And just have a look at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/) example. As per that example, just declare the activites like that. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare you tab's activities as per below -

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".readmore"> </activity>

<activity android:name=".Mainpage"></activity>

<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".contactus" ></activity>
```

And, have a look at [TabLayout](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/) tutorial.